# Implementation of Bayesian Network with continuous and discrete variable mixed

Tags: bayesian-network

is there any good software package that contains the implementation of BN with mixed continuous and discrete nodes ?

can not find one. I do not know why it is.

I would love to integrate it into KINME

Answer (score 1):

[Bayes Server](https://www.bayesserver.com/) (a commercial package) can work with both discrete and continuous nodes and has a Java API (as well as a .NET one), so you could probably code up a KNIME integration if you had the time and inclination.

Comment: This is awesome! I just want to add for someone who comes to this answer, that they also provide how to set it up in python and R .